# Rounding real numbers in Postgres 13

Tags: postgresql, rounding, rounding-error

## Errors Calling Round

I've been getting tripped up by `round()` in Postgres for *ages*, and figured I'd finally try and figure out the rules. This is the sort of error that I run into regularly:

```
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist.
```

This may make sense to others, but it's befuddled me. As best as I can figure you have to cast to `decimal/numeric`, if you want a rounded result with a fractional number. This is documented behavior, it's just a bit hard to understand why `real` and `double` can't be rounded. I've got more details below, but the long and the short of it is that I've written `round` for `double precision` and `real` columns and calculations.

## Overall Findings/Impressions

- Whole integer types round to the nearest whole integer, as you would guess.
- However, there is *no error* if you pass a number of rounding decimals into integer division.
- `decimal` and `numeric` round fine. (They're the same thing internally, as people know.)
- `real` and `double precision` aren't supported. I don't understand why, these seem like  values you would naturally want to round.
- `serial` types aren't supported, throwing an 'unknown type' error. Which I'm inclined to think is an error in my test setup, but I can't see where. And, no, I can't imagine needing to round a serial type, but I would expect them to behave like their integer counterparts.
- Division cast explicitly to

Is this correct and complete?

## Custom Functions

I'd be grateful to anyone who can help make it easier to understand why `round` behaves as it does, and point me towards a better solution than this pair of functions:

```
/*
OVERLOADING: Not my thing but, in this case, sensible.
I'm not sure if the real version is required or not.
*/

------------------------------------
-- double precision version
------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tools.round(
     value_to_round   double precision,
     round_to         integer  default 0)

    RETURNS double precision

-- Note: Not validating that the number of places in non-negative. Don't do that.

AS $BODY$

SELECT round(value_to_round::numeric, round_to)::double precision;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;

------------------------------------
-- real version
------------------------------------
-- I don't think that this is ever invoked. I have only managed to get the double version to run.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tools.round(
     value_to_round   real,
     round_to         integer  default 0)

    RETURNS real

-- Note: Not validating that the number of places in non-negative. Don't do that.

AS $BODY$

SELECT round(value_to_round::numeric, round_to)::real;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

## Test Code

To test this out, I grabbed the list of numeric types https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html, and ran similar-looking tests on each, one at a time.

```
-- Test 1: SMALLINT
-- Result: smallint, integer, 0, 0
SELECT 'smallint' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::smallint) as result_type,
        1/3::smallint as raw_result,
        round(1/3::smallint, 4);

-- Test 2: INTEGER
-- Result: integer, integer, 0, 0
SELECT 'integer' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::integer) as result_type,
        1/3::integer as raw_result,
        round(1/3::integer, 4);

-- Test 3: BIGINT
-- Result: bigint, bigint, 0, 0
SELECT 'bigint' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::bigint) as result_type,
        1/3::bigint as raw_result,
        round(1/3::bigint, 4);

-- Test 4: DECIMAL
-- Result: decimal, numeric, 0.33333333333333333333 and 0.3333
SELECT 'decimal' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::decimal) as result_type,
        1/3::decimal as raw_result,
        round(1/3::decimal, 4);

-- Test 5: NUMERIC
-- Result: 0.33333333333333333333 and 0.3333
-- Result: numeric, numeric, 0.33333333333333333333 and 0.3333
SELECT 'numeric' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::numeric) as result_type,
        1/3::numeric as raw_result,
        round(1/3::numeric, 4);

-- Test 6: REAL
-- Result: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist.
-- Note : You MAY all round for whole number division round(1/3::real), the error is only on rounding to a decimal place.
-- Note: If you check the pg_typeof(1/3::real), it's double precision, not real.
SELECT 'real' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::REAL) as result_type,
        1/3::REAL as raw_result,
        round(1/3::real,4);

-- Test 7: DOUBLE PRECISION
-- Result: ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
-- Note : You MAY all round for whole number division round(1/3::double precision), the error is only on rounding to a decimal place.
SELECT 'double precision' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::double precision) as result_type,
        1/3::double precision as raw_result,
        round(1/3::double precision, 4);

-- Test 8: SMALLSERIAL
-- Result: ERROR:  type "smallserial" does not exist. Eh? Wouldn't want to round a serial anyway but, ?
SELECT 'smallserial' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::smallserial) as result_type,
        1/3::smallserial as raw_result,
        round(1/3::smallserial, 4);

-- Test 9: SERIAL
-- Result: ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist. Eh? Wouldn't want to round a serial anyway but, ?
SELECT 'serial' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::serial) as result_type,
        1/3::serial as raw_result,
        round(1/3::serial, 4);

-- Test 10: BIGSERIAL
-- Result: ERROR:  type "bigserial" does not exist. Eh? Wouldn't want to round a serial anyway but, ?
SELECT 'bigserial' as cast_type,
        pg_typeof(1/3::bigserial) as result_type,
        1/3::bigserial as raw_result,
        round(1/3::bigserial, 4);
```

## Summary of Findings

| Test # | Casting Type | 1/3 Result Type | Example | Round to | Raw Result | Rounded Result | Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | smallint | integer | `round(1/3::real, 4)` | 4 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 2 | integer | integer | `round(1/3::integer, 4)` | 4 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 3 | bigint | bigint | `round(1/3::bigint, 4)` | 4 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 4 | decimal | numeric | `round(1/3::decimal, 4)` | 4 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.3333 |  |
| 5 | numeric | numeric | `round(1/3::numeric, 4)` | 4 | 0.333333333333333 | 0.3333 |  |
| 6 | real | double precision | `round(1/3::real, 4)` | 4 |  |  | `ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist.` |
| 6b | real | double precision | `round(1/3::real)` |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| 7 | double precision | double precision | `round(1/3::double precision, 4)` | 4 |  |  | `ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist.` |
| 7b | double precision | double precision | `round(1/3::double precision)` |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| 8 | smallserial | n/a | `round(1/3::smallserial, 4)` | 4 |  |  | `ERROR: type "smallserial" does not exist` |
| 9 | serial | n/a | `round(1/3::serial, 4)` | 4 |  |  | `ERROR: type "serial" does not exist.` |
| 10 | bigserial | n/a | `round(1/3::bigserial, 4)` | 4 |  |  | `ERROR: type "bigserial" does not exist.` |

## Answer after comments

I've gotten a couple of comments below, all of which are helpful. Looking through the past threads on hackers offers some insight. What I draw from them is that *people have been finding this confusing for over a decade.* I really love Postgres, but it can tend to favor *correctness* above *clarity*.

For what it's worth, this mostly has come up because my boss was getting "weird errors" and asked me WTF is wrong with Postgres. I had to say that I really couldn't offer any answer that he would find useful, but that I could fix it by overriding the default behavior.

I'm not saying that Postgres has a bug, but the design choice here is....unhelpful. For those of you that have been with Postgres for many, many years and/or deep in the internals, it may be easy to lose track of what an outsider or newcomer might experience. I've been working *hard* at Postgres (far from my first DB) for over four years, and I still feel like a beginner. For someone dedicating less attention to Postgres than that, confusing behavior is just going to go unexplored. Or considered a bug. (Other languages and databases make different choices about how to handle rounding on various numeric types.)

Back to specifics:

- Absolutely, you can't change the precision of a fixed-precision decimal type. But you *can* convert "rounded" places to 0. That's definitely good enough.
- I later thought "maybe `trunc` will work", it's certainly good enough for the quality of data we're dealing with. It's got the same behaviors as `round`.

As far as I can tell, my trivial functions get the job done fine for our purposes, and avoid errors that are of no benefit. So, I've overloaded `round` and `trunc` in our systems to behave the way we want, and should never have to think about this issue again.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) `serial` isn't a real data type - it's a shortcut for an integer which gets its default value from a sequence. You can't round double or floats because you can't reduce the precision of those data types. If you need that use `numeric` and stop worrying

Comment: If you want the reasoning behind the rounding behavior in Postgres see these two mailing list threads: [round(x)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9760841FB339C546BB304014810EB20D020ECBEB%40GRPGEPWMX0011.grptop.net) and [round(real,integer)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/etPan.52d053b5.6b68079a.125ef%40Butterfly.local)